# CSS DIV-based table with header and limited height showing scrollbar when necessary - percentage heights

Tags: css, html, scroll, height

I've searched high and low and cannot find a solution specific to this problem.  I'm trying to accomplish the following:

- Have a container DIV defined with a percentage height to serve as max-size container
- A secondary container DIV that provides a content size-based borde
- Have a header div that is fixed at the top of that DIV
- Have a list of DIVs (table-like) under the header
- When the list is short, the border is reduced to size of content
- When list if long (> height of outer container), scrollbar is shown for DIV list and not header.

I put together the following simplified version:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            .panel { height: 10%; border: 1px solid red; overflow: hidden; margin-top: 10px; }
            .sizer { max-height: 100%; border: 1px solid blue; }
            .header { border-bottom: 1px solid black; }
            .scroll { max-height: 100%; overflow: auto; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="panel">
            <div class="sizer">
                <div class="wrap">
                    <div class="header">Header</div>
                    <div class="scroll">
                        <div>Line1</div>
                        <div>Line2</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel">
            <div class="sizer">
                <div class="wrap">
                    <div class="header">Header</div>
                    <div class="scroll">
                        <div>Line1</div>
                        <div>Line2</div>
                        <div>Line3</div>
                        <div>Line4</div>
                        <div>Line5</div>
                        <div>Line6</div>
                        <div>Line7</div>
                        <div>Line8</div>
                        <div>Line9</div>
                        <div>Line10</div>
                        <div>Line11</div>
                        <div>Line12</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The two red boxes should be fixed size. Check
The blue box should size to be the size of the content or size of red box maximum.  Check
When contents in lower exceed red box size, scrollbar should be displayed under header.  Fail

Any change I make that gets the scrollbar displayed causes the top blue box to enlarge to the size of it's container, red box.  e.g., { .scroll height: 100% }

(The DIV.wrap does have a purpose - just not in this example.  It is intended to provide a double-border effect on the sizer, so it should be the same size as sizer all the time).

Also, I have figured out some solutions where I used fixed (px) sizes for the DIVs, but this is not necessarily desired.  Especially on DIV.panel - this must be set to a percentage height.

Comment: I'm looking to do something exactly like: [Pure CSS Scrollable Table with Fixed Header](http://www.imaputz.com/cssStuff/bigFourVersion.html), but the containing DIV is not a fixed px height - it needs to be a % of the parent

Answer (score 0):

Not completely sure i understand the question, but if you want the scroll on the list but not on the header, have you tried:

```
overflow-y:scroll;
```

on the "scroll" div instead of

```
overflow:auto?
```

Let me know

Comment: Yes.  Tried that.  The problem is more that the height of the DIV.scroll's container (DIV.wrap and DIV.sizer) will enlarge to fit DIV.scroll causing the overflow to not be triggered.  Or, when I fix the height of one of those containers, they then become fixed and do not decrease in height when the contents are smaller than DIV.panel

Comment: Could you not give the divs within .scroll a height and therefore that will trigger the overflow? eg
.scroll div {height: 20px; line-height:20px}
Or does it have to all be completely dynamic to whatever is in the divs?

Comment: Tried that too.  .scroll gets it's full height and thus is clipped by a parent's overflow: hidden.  It's like max-height on scroll is ignored.

Answer (score 0):

Ok i think maybe i worked it out. I think cause you have overflow:hidden and a height on the container div, and not the variable scroll div. Just try the code below and let me know. I have added the height of 10% to the scroll div and not the overall container. Hope thats what you were looking for

```
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        .panel { border: 1px solid red; overflow: hidden; margin-top: 10px; }
        .sizer { max-height: 100%; border: 1px solid blue;  display:block;}
        .header { border-bottom: 1px solid black; }
        .scroll { height: 10%;overflow-y: scroll; display:block; }
        .scroll div {display:block; line-height:normal; clear:both; height:20px;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="panel">
        <div class="sizer">
            <div class="wrap">
                <div class="header">Header</div>
                <div class="scroll">
                    <div>Line1</div>
                    <div>Line2</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel">
        <div class="sizer">
            <div class="wrap">
                <div class="header">Header</div>
                <div class="scroll">
                    <div>Line1</div>
                    <div>Line2</div>
                    <div>Line3</div>
                    <div>Line4</div>
                    <div>Line5</div>
                    <div>Line6</div>
                    <div>Line7</div>
                    <div>Line8</div>
                    <div>Line9</div>
                    <div>Line10</div>
                    <div>Line11</div>
                    <div>Line12</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Almost there.  The only problem is that in the "upper" section, since the size of the content is less than the panel, I need the sizer (blue border) to be reduced to only the necessary size of the content.  This is the conundrum I keep getting into - to get scrolling, I have to fix the size in the small content case, or, when autosizing, I lose the scroll.